# Django haystack how is fq(solr) populated

Tags: django, django-haystack

I am using solr as search backend with django-haystack. When viewing the logs I can see that query to solr is having "fq" populated.

`INFO: [] webapp=/solr path=/select/ params={fl=*+score&start=0&q=yyy&wt=json&fq=django_ab:(xxx)&rows=10} hits=5 status=0 QTime=0`

My doubt is how this how is "fq" parameter i populated by haystack. I am using SearchQuerySet.filter to add search in solr documents.
Another thing I noticed is no matter what the search query is fq remains same. Is fq related to the django application whose model is indexed? Should I be worrying about having it a constant.

Answer (score 1):

you may want to check here
https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py

if narrow_queries is not None:
            kwargs['fq'] = list(narrow_queries)

Answer (score 1):

Haystack itself uses the `fq` parameter to return only hits that have a certain Django `ContentType` (in effect a certain Model class).

About SOLR's `fq`:

This parameter is allowed multiple times in queries. The resulting subset of hits of a certain `fq` parameter is cached. Thus, it makes sense to use the `fq` for subsets that are often retrieved (like category searches for example, that are used in menus on your site).

To make use of the `fq` parameter via Haystack, use `narrow()` on the SearchQuerySet:

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html?highlight=narrow#SearchQuerySet.narrow